# S3 upload files with public

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wasabi

I have a website working with nodeJs. In here users can upload their pictures. I'm using Wasabi to store that pictures.
My problem is everytime a user send a picture to server it will save it with private condition. Because of that after uploading users can't see the picture. I need to make it public on the bucket so users can see it.
My all buckets are free to read but everytime I upload a file it will be private. How can I make every uploaded picture public?

these are my upload params

```js
const paramsForUpload = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: filePath,
      Body: file.data,
    };
    const options = {
      partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB
      queueSize: 10,
    };
s3.upload(paramsForUpload,options, (err) =>{
....
})
```

My policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AddPerm",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

You can make public upload with adding

```
      ACL: 'public-read',
```

to your upload params like

```
    const paramsForUpload = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: filePath,
      Body: file.data,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The bucket policy should refer to **the contents** of the bucket, with a trailing `/*`:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
    }
  ]
}
```